# Face cards do not show up on poker package (pst-poker)

Tags: graphics, errors, packages, package-options, includegraphics

My `.tex` looks like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-poker} 

\begin{document}

\crdQs
\Qs
\crdAs
\As

\end{document}
```

Everything compiles great except for `\crdQs`. I am getting the following error:

> Undefined control sequence.  \includegraphics{Queen-\pkr@suitname - \pkr@facecol}

I suspect this has something to do with the graphics of the face card? But I thought that the graphics were included in the package. What am I missing?

**Edit: For graphics to show up `\usepackage{graphicx}` is a necessary addition to the preamble. Maybe there is another way too, but that seemed to do the trick.**

Comment: I'll fix it in the package.

Comment: @Herbert The documentation also mentions using the `poker2` package which doesn't seem to exist.

Comment: sure, no problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently I needed to add `\usepackage{graphicx}` in the preamble for the graphics to show up.